# Word replace italicized text

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there any way in MS word that we can match all italicized text and bring brackets {..} before and after them?

For example, I have *mag pal two*: in another page I have *woke me up*: and many other italicized sentences

What I want is to find them and replace them with a bracket around them

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using "Find and replace" option in Microsoft Word. Here, I have a word document with many italic text. I have highlighted them in yellow *for* *our convenience*:

[image]

Press `Ctrl+H` to go to "Find and Replace" menu. Click on `More`:

[image]

Click on `Format` and then `Font...`:

[image]

Select `Font style` as `Italic` and click `OK`:

[image]

Leave the `Find what:` blank.

In `Replace with:` enter `{^&}`

If you've done everything right, "Find and Replace" will look like this at last:

[image]

Click `Replace All` button.

This is what you will get at the end:

[image]

**EDIT:** You've got a group of words (or we can call it a sentence) in italics just like this:

[image]

*(I've highlighted in yellow for convenience)*

For your information, **I have applied the very same method and it works fine in this case as well.** This is what I achieved doing the same thing I mentioned above:

[image]

So, I believe, this finally solves your problem.

I hope this helps. **Tell me how it does** :)

Comment: thanks for your answer but the problem is that I have sentence of italic that I need to put bracket or I might need to put tab before and after that if there was only one word it was simple just like what have you done before please let me know it you have any solution for sentence of italic like I said in my questioning

Comment: Can you please elaborate? So you have a whole sentence in italics?

Comment: I've just checked and the method I mentioned works fine in your special case as well. For more info, see my updated answer. Give a try and tell how it does :)

Comment: thanks so much that is work but I have one other problem in my file that the space between the italics are regular that is why it doesn't work for the first time is there still a way to fix that? thanks

Comment: If this worked, please mark it as correct answer. And for your another question, ask it separately because the answer is already too long :|