# Microsoft Word Text processing

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an entry like this:

- abaeh [a.baeh] v.

  1. jenguk. *akik dik yak*: jenguk kakek
  2. peiksa. *bubuteak malam*: periksa bubu

What I need to do is insert a tab before and after italics; How do I do this in MS Word?

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, go to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1549778/word-replace-italic-text) on your other question and convert to this form:  
 *(Add a curly bracket before and after italic by following the above given link)*

[image: Screenshot 1]

- Replace left curly brackets with a tab:

  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> > **Find what:** <kbd>{</kbd> > **Replace with:** `^t` > **Replace All**
- Replace right curly brackets with a tab:

  - **Find what:** `}` > **Replace with:** `^t` > **Replace All**

This is what you will get at the end: [image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: thanks so much that is what I want but the latest answer that you said I tried that but that bring brackets around each word not each phrase like the one that we have here

Comment: thanks so much that is work but my file has another problem that the space between the italic words are regular that is why it doesn't work for my file is there any way to fix that?